# Axis2 WS-Security Running on Java EE Application Server

Tags: jboss, apache-axis, ws-security, websphere-7, weblogic11g

I have Axis2 web services running in an Application Server (like JBoss, WebSphere and Weblogic) and till now I am passing the user details within a request and  authenticating the user before processing it.

The next step is that I want to delegate the authentication bit to the Java EE Application Server and once authenticated the application server should pass the UserPrinciple which I will be using as context to execute the request.

I am not sure if I have asked the question correctly? I think I am mixing the WebContainer authentication with WS-Security stuff.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction with some documentation which I can refer as start-up guide.

Comment: Let me rephrase it...I want to use axis2 web service and want to do an authentication and pass a RPINCIPLE to my service which I will then use to further set my contexts etc...regards

Comment: Can someone please help me sort out this problem as all the samples I have found just explain how to use CallBack to handle the username and password but I couldn't find any information on setting up the user or principle which then I can use later....can someone help please...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have tried a solution and it worked to some extent. Here are details;

Created TestService with following services.xml

```
<serviceGroup>
    <service name="TestWebService" scope="application" targetNamespace="http://TestServiceWs"> 
        <schema schemaNamespace="http://TestServiceWs"/>
        <description>Test POJO Axis2 AAR deployment</description>
        <parameter name="ServiceClass">test.TestServiceWS</parameter>
        <messageReceivers>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-only"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCInOnlyMessageReceiver"/>
            <messageReceiver mep="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/wsdl/in-out"
                class="org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver"/>
        </messageReceivers>
    </service>

    <module ref="rampart" />

    <parameter name="InflowSecurity">
      <action>
        <items>UsernameToken Timestamp</items>
        <passwordCallbackClass>test.PWHandlerServer</passwordCallbackClass>
      </action>
    </parameter>
</serviceGroup>
```

Implemented **PWHandlerServer.java**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;

import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class PWHandlerServer implements CallbackHandler {

    // the username and password we expect incoming WS calls to use
    private String user = "wsuser";
    private String pwd = "wspwd";

    public void handle (Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            if (callbacks[i] instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {
                WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                System.out.println("identifier: "+pc.getIdentifer()+", usage: "+pc.getUsage());

                if (pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN) {
                    // for passwords sent in digest mode we need to provide the password,
                    // because the original one can't be un-digested from the message

                    // we can throw either of the two Exception types if authentication fails
                    if (! user.equals(pc.getIdentifer()))
                        throw new IOException("unknown user: "+pc.getIdentifer());

                    // this will throw an exception if the passwords don't match
                    pc.setPassword(pwd);

                } else if (pc.getUsage() == WSPasswordCallback.USERNAME_TOKEN_UNKNOWN) {
                    // for passwords sent in cleartext mode we can compare passwords directly

                    if (! user.equals(pc.getIdentifer()))
                        throw new IOException("unknown user: "+pc.getIdentifer());

                    // we can throw either of the two Exception types if authentication fails
                    if (! pwd.equals(pc.getPassword()))
                        throw new IOException("password incorrect for user: "+pc.getIdentifer());
                }
                // If everything is OK then set the context and move on
                TestRequestContext ctx = new TestRequestContext(pc.getIdentifer());
                TestRequestContext.setRequestContext(ctx);

            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Implemented **TestRequestContext**

```
package test;


class TestRequestContext {
    private final static ThreadLocal<TestRequestContext> currentContext = new ThreadLocal<TestRequestContext>();

    public static void setRequestContext(TestRequestContext context) {
        currentContext.set(context);
    }

    public static TestRequestContext getRequestContext() {
        return currentContext.get();
    }

    public static void clearRequestContext() {
        currentContext.remove();
    }

    private String userPrincipal;

    public TestRequestContext(String principal) {
        this.userPrincipal = principal;
    }

    public String getUserPrincipal(){
        return this.userPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Now I should be able to access my TestRequestContext.getUserPricipal() in my web service class and pass it on DB for transaction and switching a security context. The only problem is when I am trying to access the service via SoapUI its giving me following exception;

```
    15:07:34,924 INFO  [STDOUT] identifier: wsuser, usage: 5
15:08:48,081 INFO  [STDOUT] [ERROR] WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed (actions mismatch)
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSDoAllReceiver: security processing failed (actions mismatch)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processBasic(WSDoAllReceiver.java:344)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllReceiver.processMessage(WSDoAllReceiver.java:86)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.WSDoAllHandler.invoke(WSDoAllHandler.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:318)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:160)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:144)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Within SoapUI, I am simply using 'Auth' tab to set username and password and invoke? do I need to setup anything else before invocation.

Also, the approach to use ThreadLocal is correct or I can access the principle some otherway as well?

Thanks.

Comment: I have sorted the exception as well by removing the 'Timestamp' from <items> node in InflowSecurity. SoapUI was not adding the timestamp infromation in header hence it was failing. Now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the username passed in the SOAP header in below format as well. You can access this in the operation, before authorizing. You may not require TestRequestContext class to store the username.Please let me know if anyone do not agree.

```
MessageContext msgContext = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();                   
// Getting HttpServletRequest from Message Context 
String username = (String)msgContext 
                           .getProperty(RampartMessageData.USERNAME);
```